# Not able to access eclipse che server running on docker in multi-user mode through browser

Tags: docker, eclipse-che

As part of POC I am trying to test eclipse che in **multi-user** mode using docker. Below are the steps I have followed to install che server

1.Because of restricted network I've downloaded all the required images as tar files and loaded the images using **docker load** command in offline mode

2.Once all the required images are available I ran below command 
**docker run -it -e CHE_MULTIUSER=true -e CHE_HOST=XXX.XX.51.91 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /opt/disk1/workspaces/RRN/backup:/data che start --offline**

3.Above command successfully launched che,postrgess and keycloak containers and che server is running on 8080 port and keyClok is running on 5050 port

4.To test the IDE, I have opened the browser and issued below command and received **"Authorization token is missed,click here to reload"** the message. 
http://XXX.XX.51.91:8080

Kindly help me what's the issue and how to resolve.

Do I need to do any configuration settings in the keycloak which is running on port 5050

For more details about the error please refer attached screen shot.

Regards,
Ravi.

[Click here to see actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24rlY.png)

[click here to see docker images list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yge16.png)

Answer (score 0):

To run Eclips Che 7 you need minikube or minishift environment and there is no offline mode.

Comment: Hi tolusha, Instead of using che 7, I have used che-6 and started the ide in multi user mode with below command. All three containers are up and running  and launched IDE through browser. However creation of workspace was failed with below error.

**Error: Failed to run the workspace: "Server 'wsagent/http' in machine 'dev-machine' not available."**

docker run  -it -e CHE_HOST=34.77.66.145  -e CHE_MULTIUSER=true -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/infra-build/raviche:/data eclipse/che:6.17.0 start

Please help what could be the issue, I didn't find any info from logs

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Che will not support running on bare docker as it was mentioned for example in this comment: https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/13113